# Computing x^y with GCC vector intrinsics

Tags: c, performance, optimization, gcc, sse

Suppose I have a 2 element vector defines as follows (using the GCC syntax for packed vectors)

```
// packed vector of 2-elements
typedef double v2d __attribute__((vector_size(sizeof(double)*2)));

v2d x = ...;
double y = ...;

x[0] = pow(x[0], y)
x[1] = pow(x[1], y)
```

I'd like to know if there's a faster way to do the two power computations using vector operations.  The architecture is GCC on x86-64 and platform specific code is OK.

Comment: Implementing a generic power function is difficult as it is since you may need both `exp()` and `log()`. There may likely be too much branching to be able to get a worthwhile speedup via vectorizing. But I'm just speculating though.

Comment: No, the SIMD instruction set doesn't have any operations that allow speeding up pow().  SSE2 only has add, sub, mul, div, max, min and sqrt.  There's not even a non-vectorized instruction for it.

Comment: There may be some hope if "y" is limited to unsigned int instead of double. Indeed, with the classic "shift-and-multiply" algorithm the two vector's elements could be evaluated in parallel. Just my guess.

Comment: [SSE vectorization of math `pow` function gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6918141/995714), [`pow` for SSE types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25936031/995714)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this should be possible if you have no special cases (negative numbers, 0, 1, NaN etc...) so that the code path is linear.

[Here](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c) is the generic code for the `pow` function for IEEE754 doubles, it has no looping constructs, so if you flesh out all the special cases, vectorization seems straightforward. Have fun.

Comment: Haha... I see what you mean by "have fun". :)

Comment: You link is not  working.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the elements directly and with the right options GCC and ICC will use a vectorized `pow` function

```
#include <math.h>
typedef double vnd __attribute__((vector_size(sizeof(double)*2)));

vnd foo(vnd x, vnd y) {
    #pragma omp simd
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) x[i] = pow(x[i], y[i]); 
    return x;
}
```

With just `-O2` ICC generates simply `call __svml_pow2`. [SVML](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524289) (Short Vector Math Library) is Intel's vectorized math library. [With `-Ofast -fopenmp`](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec) GCC generates simply `call _ZGVbN2vv___pow_finite`.

Clang does not vectorize it.

https://godbolt.org/g/pjpzFX