# VC2012 where to find _mm256_pow_pd?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intrinsics

Using Visual Studio 2012/C++:

I need to apply gamma correction to my resampler code.  From [Intels Docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/?wapkw=intrinsics#expand=5509,2121&text=_mm256_pow_pd) I learned that there should be the intrinsic `_mm256_pow_pd()`, but I can't find it.

Planned use:

```
_mm256_storeu_pd(&destinationData[y*dst4+x], _mm256_pow_pd(akku, _mm256_broadcast_sd(&gamma)));
```

Any ideas where Microsoft has hidden this intrinsic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I didn't google enough.  This SO answer implicitly answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515534/2896592

Content: `_mm256_pow_pd` is from Intel's SVML library - it's not really an intrinsic.

Workaround: take a look at [Agner Fog's vector library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass)